# Restrict Azure storage account access to allow only my App Services, blocking remote access

Tags: azure, azure-app-services, azure-storage

I would like to block remote access, allowing only the App Services in the same subscription to access my storage in production.

I tried using Virtual Network and Access control (IAM) but without success.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Web Apps configure [VNet Integration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet) for the Vnet you like to configure Azure Storage. Then configure the storage account to Access only from specific network ([Firewall and Networking](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security)) you specified in the Azure App Service. Then Configure that VNet with [Service Endpoints](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoints-overview) to Azure Storage.

Comment: So do I need to set up a Firewall even to only on Azure? I checked the pricing and to add a firewall this will cost me +- $900/month

Comment: No need of using Azure firewall in here what i mentioned was firewall and networking feature in storage account.

Comment: I showed the case to a customer engineer at Microsoft, he couldn't figure out at the call. I am waiting for their response.